# Why is my python programming fixing the capitalization incorrectly and replacing the punctuation incorrectly?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a python program that has several functions that manipulate text. Some of these functions include counting non-whitespace characters, counting words, fixing capitalization, replacing punctuation, and shortening spaces. However, my code is failing two unittest:

1. Tests that fix_capitalization() capitalizes 3 characters in "we'll continue our quest in space. there will be more shuttle flights and more shuttle crews and, yes; more volunteers, more civilians, more teachers in space. nothing ends here; our hopes and our journeys continue!".

My output: fix_capitalization() incorrectly edits the string.
Number of letters capitalized: We'll continue our quest in space.  There will be more shuttle flights and more shuttle crews and,  yes;  more volunteers, more civilians,  more teachers in space.  Nothing ends here;  our hopes and our journeys continue!
Edited text: 3

2. Tests that replace_punctuation() replaces 1 exclamation point and 2 semicolons in "we'll continue our quest in space. there will be more shuttle flights and more shuttle crews and, yes; more volunteers, more civilians, more teachers in space. nothing ends here; our hopes and our journeys continue!".

My output:
Punctuation replaced
exclamation_count: 1
semicolon_count: 2
replace_punctuation() incorrectly edits the string.
Edited text: ("we'll continue our quest in space.  there will be more shuttle flights and more shuttle crews and,  yes,  more volunteers, more civilians,  more teachers in space.  nothing ends here,  our hopes and our journeys continue.", 1, 2)

Here is my code:

```
def print_menu():
    print("MENU")
    print("c - Number of non-whitespace characters")
    print("w - Number of words")
    print("f - Fix capitalization")
    print("r - Replace punctuation")
    print("s - Shorten spaces")
    print("q - Quit")
    print('')

def get_num_of_non_WS_characters(string_input):
    return len([char for char in string_input if not char.isspace()])

def get_num_of_words(string_input):
    return len(string_input.split())

def fix_capitalization(string_input):
    num_capitalized = 0
    output = ""
    capitalize_next = True
    for char in string_input:
        if capitalize_next and char.islower():
            output += char.upper()
            num_capitalized += 1
            capitalize_next = False
        else:
            output += char
        if char in ".?!":
            capitalize_next = True
    return num_capitalized, output

def replace_punctuation(string_input, exclamation_count=0, semicolon_count=0):
    output = ""
    for char in string_input:
        if char == "!":
            output += "."
            exclamation_count += 1
        elif char == ";":
            output += ","
            semicolon_count += 1
        else:
            output += char
    print("Punctuation replaced")
    print("exclamation_count:", exclamation_count)
    print("semicolon_count:", semicolon_count)
    return output, exclamation_count, semicolon_count

def shorten_space(string_input):
    output = ""
    last_char_space = False
    for char in string_input:
        if not char.isspace():
            output += char
            last_char_space = False
        elif not last_char_space:
            output += " "
            last_char_space = True
    return output

def execute_menu(choice, string_input):
    if choice == "c":
        print("Number of non-whitespace characters:", get_num_of_non_WS_characters(string_input))
        print('')
    elif choice == "w":
        print("Number of words:", get_num_of_words(string_input))
        print('')
    elif choice == "f":
        num_capitalized, output = fix_capitalization(string_input)
        print("Number of letters capitalized:", num_capitalized)
        print("Edited text:", output)
        print('')
    elif choice == "r":
        output, exclamation_count, semicolon_count = replace_punctuation(string_input)
        print("Punctuation replaced")
        print("exclamation_count:", exclamation_count)
        print("semicolon_count:", semicolon_count)
        print("Edited text:", output)
        print('')
    elif choice == "s":
        print("Edited text:", shorten_space(string_input))
        print('')
    elif choice == "q":
        quit()
    else:
        print("Invalid choice. Please choose a valid option.")


def main():
    string_input = input("Enter a sample text:\n")
    print('')
    print("You entered:", string_input)
    print('')
    print_menu()
    while True:
        choice = input("Choose an option:\n")
        if choice == "q":
            quit()
        execute_menu(choice, string_input)
        print_menu()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: This seems to be a problem with the code not matching the tests, rather than anything fundamentally being wrong with the code.  For #1, `fix_capitalization()` seems to be expected to return the two values in the opposite order.  For #2, `replace_punctuation()` is expected to return just the edited string, not the counts.